# How to turn on Auto Close Tag and Auto-Find Closing Tag

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using Visual Studio Code without trouble for approximately 1 year.

However a few days ago 2 features inexplicably turned off.

1) Auto Close Tag stopped.
When I open a DIV a closing DIV is no longer created.

2) Auto-find the closing tag stopped.
When I select an opening DIV it no longer highlights the closing DIV but instead highlights all DIVs in the entire document.

I believe these 2 features have been standard for some time.
[August 2017 (version 1.16)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_html-close-tags)

I checked my preferences by going to,

`File > Preferences > Extensions > HTML`

**Auto Closing Tags**
Enable/disable Autoclosing of HTML tags.

The box for Auto Closing Tags was checkmarked.

I'm at a loss.  I'm not sure where else to check or which preferences need to be changed to get it back to the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

I found this elsewhere on StackOverflow:
"I had the same problem. After reviewing the answer above, I noticed that VS Code auto-detected a different language than HTML, even though the file I was editing had the ".html" extension. After selecting HTML as the working language, the editor now auto-closes the tags."
and this:
"After I change the environment it be solved!"

Comment: Please link the answer you are quoting and tailoring to this question (that part is well done, though in the future you might consider flagging a question as duplicate). Also please remove anything which sounds like "Me too." because you risk being misunderstood as not contributing anything else. Mostly everythig before "i found this".

Answer (score 0):

**install this extension**

---

> highlight-matching-tag

---

and change the settings.json to
some changes in setting, goto file->preferences->setting, you can now see User settings in the right hand side, add the following code

```
"files.associations": {
// extension name : html
"*.php": "html",
"*.html": "html"
}


"highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
 "opening": {
     "full": {
         "highlight": "rgba(255, 202, 202, 0.9)"
     }
 }
 }
```

and you are ready to go. Enjoy :)